# 2 column collectionview sizing problem in some iphones

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am using this code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let padding: CGFloat =  50
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
    }
```

I am able to get a 2 column collection view on all iPhones except iPhone X and iphone XR, I don't know why

[image]

How to force 2 columns for all iPhones?

Comment: Check the frame (width) of the UICollectionView when called, and is there any margins ?

Comment: do you set the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` of the colleectionView? if so do you handle the `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` Hope this helps

Comment: @Utku Dalmaz I am seeing the exact same issue & it's frustrating. Did you find the cause/solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you calculate `width` according to `safeAreaLayoytGuide` and, if you're using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, `sectionInset`. For `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` the following code will calculate proper *width*:

```
    let sectionInset = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset
    let width = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
                - sectionInset.left 
                - sectionInset.right
                - collectionView.contentInset.left
                - collectionView.contentInset.right
```

If you need two columns, than item width will be calculated like that:

```
let space: CGFloat = 10.0
let itemSize = CGSize(width: (width - space) / 2, height: 100 /*DESIRED HEIGHT*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout of your `collectionView` by creating new layout and set it's `itemSize`, `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` and then assign new layout as `collectionView.collectionViewLayout`:

```
func setCollectionViewLayout(withPadding padding: CGFloat) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let size = (collectionView.frame.width - padding) / 2
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

and then call this method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (this is moment when frames are loaded and you can calculate with `collectionView`'s frame)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    setCollectionViewLayout(withPadding: 50)
}
```

**Note:** I would recommend you to set leading and trailing constraints of `collectionView` to constant 25 instead of using padding